# LoopTools Bridge not working

Tags: selection-tools

I tried to join the two selected loops by pressing W and LoopTools and selecting Bridge but it came out distorted. Please see attached .blend file.

[image]

Comment: Generally, it would be helpful to see screenshots of what was wrong aside from link to .blend in your questions. The problem was with flipped normals. If you recalculated normals *before* bridging it would work as expected even with LoopTools.

Comment: No, that was the first thing I checked. Flip normal, recalculate normal doesn't change the outcome. Anyway, I used the method suggested by Cegaton and it worked.

Comment: I don't know what you checked, in the file you uploaded this worked perfectly because as I wrote some of the normals were flipped. Flipping them is not the best way, it's best to recalculate them first. Make sure to select adjacent faces, and then using `Ctrl`+`N`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your edge loops have the same number of vertices you can use the [bridge edge loops](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#modeling-meshes-editing-bridge-edge-loops) tool to join them.

In Edit mode, select the edge loops you want to connect, press the space bar and type bridge edge loops.

[image]

After that just recalculate your normals: Select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

[image]